# 3-тий слой Java EE security mechanisms

Tags: java, java-ee, soap

Message-Layer Security

[Security Mechanisms](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-intro002.htm)

**In message-layer security, security information is contained within the SOAP message and/or SOAP message attachment, which allows security information to travel along with the message or attachment.**

- Если кто сможет перевести в простых словах (выделенные строчки), на русский язык, буду очень рад!
- Непонял по поводу SOAP в данной статье, Message-Layer-Security основывается исключительно на SOAP протоколе ?

For example, a portion of the message may be signed by a sender and encrypted for a particular receiver. When sent from the initial sender, the message may pass through intermediate nodes before reaching its intended receiver. In this scenario, the encrypted portions continue to be opaque to any intermediate nodes and can be decrypted only by the intended receiver. For this reason, message-layer security is also sometimes referred to as end-to-end security.

The advantages of message-layer security include the following.

Security stays with the message over all hops and after the message arrives at its destination.

Security can be selectively applied to different portions of a message and, if using XML Web Services Security, to attachments.

Message security can be used with intermediaries over multiple hops.

Message security is independent of the application environment or transport protocol.

The disadvantage of using message-layer security is that it is relatively complex and adds some overhead to processing

Comment: В простых словах выделенные строчки: на уровне сообщений все данные, обеспечивающие безопасность сообщений, путешествуют вместе с сообщением в теле SOAP сообщения или в прикреплённых данных SOAP. Ну т.е. не отделяются метаданные от данных.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что здесь не биржа переводов.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как сайт предназначен для общения на русском языке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, Message-layer security - это часть протокола soap. Перевод может звучать примерно так: в message-layer security, информация о безопасности содержится в самом soap сообщении и/или вложении в soap сообщение, что позволяет этой самой информации о безопасности проделать маршрут от сервера к серверу *вместе* с soap сообщением или вложением.

Пример такого soap сообщения можно нагуглить, например, в документации ibm.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <wsse:Security xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
                xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">

  <wsse:BinarySecurityToken 
                EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 1 
                ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509" 
                wsu:Id="x509cert00">MIIChDCCAe2gAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAwMQswCQYDVQQGEwJHQjEMMAoGA1UEChMD
                                    SUJNMRMwEQYDVQQDEwpXaWxsIFlhdGVzMB4XDTA2MDEzMTAwMDAwMFoXDTA3MDEzMTIzNTk1OVow
                                    MDELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxDDAKBgNVBAoTA0lCTTETMBEGA1UEAxMKV2lsbCBZYXRlczCBnzANBgkq
                                    hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEArsRj/n+3RN75+jaxuOMBWSHvZCB0egv8qu2UwLWEeiogePsR
                                    6Ku4SuHbBwJtWNr0xBTAAS9lEa70yhVdppxOnJBOCiERg7S0HUdP7a8JXPFzA+BqV63JqRgJyxN6
                                    msfTAvEMR07LIXmZAte62nwcFrvCKNPCFIJ5mkaJ9v1p7jkCAwEAAaOBrTCBqjA/BglghkgBhvhC
                                    AQ0EMhMwR2VuZXJhdGVkIGJ5IHRoZSBTZWN1cml0eSBTZXJ2ZXIgZm9yIHovT1MgKFJBQ0YpMDgG
                                    A1UdEQQxMC+BEVdZQVRFU0BVSy5JQk0uQ09NggdJQk0uQ09NhgtXV1cuSUJNLkNPTYcECRRlBjAO
                                    BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAfYwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMiPX6VZKP5+mSOY1TLNQGVvJzu+MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
                                    BQUAA4GBAHdrS409Jhoe67pHL2gs7x4SpV/NOuJnn/w25sjjop3RLgJ2bKtK6RiEevhCDim6tnYW
                                    NyjBL1VdN7u5M6kTfd+HutR/HnIrQ3qPkXZK4ipgC0RWDJ+8APLySCxtFL+J0LN9Eo6yjiHL68mq
                                    uZbTH2LvzFMy4PqEbmVKbmA87alF
  </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
  <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
   <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/> 2 
   <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
     <wsse:Reference URI="#x509cert00" 
                     ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509"/>  3 
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
   <xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:CipherValue>M6bDQtJrvX0pEjAEIcf6bq6MP3ySmB4TQOa/B5UlQj1vWjD56V+GRJbF7ZCES5ojwCJHRVKW1ZB5 4 
                      Mb+aUzSWlsoHzHQixc1JchgwCiyIn+E2TbG3R9m0zHD3XQsKTyVaOTlR7VPoMBd1ZLNDIomxjZn2
                      p7JfxywXkObcSLhdZnc=</xenc:CipherValue>
   </xenc:CipherData>
   <xenc:ReferenceList>
    <xenc:DataReference URI="#Enc1"/>
   </xenc:ReferenceList>
  </xenc:EncryptedKey>
 </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="Enc1" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content">
  <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/> 5 
  <xenc:CipherData>
   <xenc:CipherValue>kgvqKnMcgIUn7rl1vkFXF0g4SodEd3dxAJo/mVN6ef211B1MZelg7OyjEHf4ZXwlCdtOFebIdlnK 6 
                     rrksql1Mpw6So7ID8zav+KPQUKGm4+E=</xenc:CipherValue>
  </xenc:CipherData>
 </xenc:EncryptedData>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Хочу уточнить следующее: То есть все сообшения использующие SOAP протокол являются "безопасными" ?

Comment: Ничего подобного.Чаще всего message-layer security не используется вообще. Однако при интеграции, например, с некоторомы сервисами гугла придётся в этом разбираться, потому что они требуют поддержки этой технологии

Comment: Можно узнать почему чаше всего этот слой не используется ?

Comment: потому что soap сам по себе не самый простой и приятный в использовании протокол, а подобные предосторожности обычно кажутся людям избыточными, учитывая, что http траффик обычно и так в ssl заворачивается.